# When running BH Procedure and there are different types of statistical tests, are they all included?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate

Let's say I'm running 100 statistical tests. Some of them are t tests, some are ANOVAs (and for each ANOVA subsequent post-hoc t tests should a significant result be obtained), some of them correlations, and so on... Given the large number of tests I want to apply BH Procedure to control false discovery rate. My questions are as follows:

1. Does BH procedure get applied to ALL tests at once - in other words, all p values are included in the same BH Procedure for all t tests, correlations, ANOVAs, post-hoc t tests for ANOVAs, and so on??? Or do I do a separate BH procedure for each type of test (i.e., one for correlations, one for ANOVAs, one for t tests, etc.)?
2. Let's say that 90 of the 100 tests are correlations. Is it ok to apply BH procedure to just the correlations, and not apply any sort of correction to the other tests (i.e., the t tests, ANOVAs, etc.)??

Thanks in advance,

FBH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to your first question**: For BH it is **not** necessary to have all tests be of the same type or to test the same hypothesis.

**Answer to your second question**: Sure, you can choose to apply BH to only a subset of your p-values.

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: @FastBallooningHead If you are satisfied with the answer, please consider accepting it. See: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)